# Call with 2 parameters crashes, complaining that it takes 1 argument

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Why does the following call to `jinja_render()` crash?

```
def jinja_render(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class Default(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        jinja_render('welcome.html', {'username': 'test'})
```

This is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Stefano\workspace\stefanomenci-test\test.py", line 19, in get
    jinja_render('welcome.html', {'username': 'test'})
TypeError: jinja_render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def jinja_render(template, **params):
```

means that, it accepts only one non-named parameter and all of them should be named parameters . To fix this error, you can call the function like this

```
jinja_render('welcome.html', username = 'test')
```

when we call like this, `welcome.html` is a non-named parameter, where is `test` is a named parameter and the name of the parameter is `username`. There is another way to call this,

```
jinja_render('welcome.html', **{'username': 'test'})
```

This way we can unpack the values from the dictionary as named parameters to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the documentation relative to the function arguments: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments